# Youtube API v2 client for Python

Tags: python, youtube-api

YouTube API v1 has been [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v1_deprecation_notice) and switching to v2 or later is recommended. However Python seems to be the only language left with v1 client. PHP, Java and others got v2.

1. Has python client been abandoned by YT team? (similar to how Facebook withdraw their Python SDK)
2. Are there any other 3rd party YT clients for v2?
3. Do I really have to develop from scratch to get v2 compatibility?

Comment: I highly doubt the YT team has abandoned python; large chunks of  infrastructure are built with the language. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know that. This is why I'm totally surprised that they lag with v2 client so long :(

Comment: There is a python client listed on the v2 page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/code#Python

Comment: Even better, there is a v3 (beta) client: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries

Comment: man you didnt look very hard apparently @OP

Comment: @Martijn Pieters YouTube Developer's Guide for Python on http://developers.google.com/youtube/code#Python links to v1 documentation.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Python is used so heavily within Google, you'd think they'd update this already...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately atm Python SDK supports v1 only, more details on YouTube API forum [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/youtube-api-gdata/EQJKi-gjxX8/discussion)